# How could I make this form centered on my page?

Tags: html, css

So I want to make a message form centered on my page, but I do not know why, it is not working how I make that.
My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Kapcsolat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Sanyigarázs</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="rolunk.html">Rólunk</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
                        <li><a href="weboldalrol.html">Weboldalról</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <form class="form-inline">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Ide írja keresését." aria-label="Keresés">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Keresés</button>
                    </form> -->
                </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <form id="uzenetes" action="emailtest.php" method="post">
                <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Név</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="username"
                    size="20" maxlength="150" width="150"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>E-mail cím</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="address"
                    size="20" maxlength="150" width="150"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tárgy</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="subject"
                size="20" maxlength="150"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Üzenet</td>
                    <td><textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Ide írja üzenetét..."  size="20" maxlength="150"></textarea></td>
                 </tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="button" type="submit"
                    value="Elküldés"/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My css are:

```
    form { 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        width:250px;
        margin-top: 15%;
        }
```

and

```
body {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
.thumbnail {
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.thumbnail:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.tested {
    font-size: 140%;
}
.bug {
    padding: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.navbar-inverse:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
} 
.weboldalroltext {
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
body { 
padding-top: 70px; 
}
.mainHeader {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.navbar {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 20px;
}
a:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: solid 3px #fff;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  a:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
.helloka {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
hr {
    height: 10px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
form {
    padding-left: 80%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 150%;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

I am a bit bad of designing things so do not be mad at me if I made terrible things in the css codes.
So what I want is center the #uzenetes form on the screen. Thanks for your help, Kristof.

Comment: Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete `width: 150%;` and  `padding-left: 80%;` from `form`. Because you've created a second form css in below.

```css
 form { 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        width:250px;
        margin-top: 15%;
        }

body {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
.thumbnail {
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.thumbnail:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.tested {
    font-size: 140%;
}
.bug {
    padding: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.navbar-inverse:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
} 
.weboldalroltext {
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
body { 
padding-top: 70px; 
}
.mainHeader {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.navbar {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 20px;
}
a:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: solid 3px #fff;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  a:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
.helloka {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
hr {
    height: 10px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
form {  
    padding-top: 10px;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Kapcsolat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Sanyigarázs</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="rolunk.html">Rólunk</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
                        <li><a href="weboldalrol.html">Weboldalról</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <form class="form-inline">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Ide írja keresését." aria-label="Keresés">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Keresés</button>
                    </form> -->
                </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <form id="uzenetes" action="emailtest.php" method="post">
                <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Név</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="username"
                    size="20" maxlength="150" width="150"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>E-mail cím</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="address"
                    size="20" maxlength="150" width="150"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tárgy</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="subject"
                size="20" maxlength="150"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Üzenet</td>
                    <td><textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Ide írja üzenetét..."  size="20" maxlength="150"></textarea></td>
                 </tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="button" type="submit"
                    value="Elküldés"/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```